Using AWS Step Functions to Dynamically write DynamoDB records
I'm working with AWS Step Functions to save records to DynamoDB. I am trying to control the name of the DynamoDB record based on the input
Based on an input of number1, the record should be 'lesser' or 'greater' for example.
const saveInDynamoDbState = new DynamoPutItem(this, 'saveInDynamoDbState', {
      table: props.table,
      item: {
        id: DynamoAttributeValue.fromString(
          JsonPath.stringAt(
            "States.Format('{}', (JsonPath.numberAt('$.number1') > 0 ? 'greater' : 'lesser'))",
          ),
        ),
       ....
     }
    });

but it seems like the logic is being ignored. I asked Amazon Q and it recommended States.MathMin/States.MathMax which I don't even think exists based on these docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-math-operation )

Could you add more information to help us to understand the question?

I'm trying to dynamically name the record using logic based on the input. I don't know if the name is pre-computed but this result seems to be ignored (JsonPath.numberAt('$.number1') > 0 ? 'greater' : 'lesser'). I want to know why, and how I need to write it.
